# How to enable "Expand all" in response samples in the Redoc page provided by FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi, redoc

In Redoc, you can open the Response samples using the "Expand all" button:

[image]

I want to put this as the default value via `custom_openapi()`. Here is my code:

```python
def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title=title,
        version="1.0",
        description=description,
        routes=app.routes,

    )
    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema


openapi_schema = custom_openapi()
```

How can I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Redoc supports a `expandResponses` as one of its [configuration options](https://github.com/redocly/redoc#redoc-options-object), I'm not familiar with passing the Redoc configuration within FastAPI but setting the value `"all"`, it should show all responses expanded.